# How do I run php-fpm when I start docker container?

Tags: php, docker, nginx

How can I automatically run `php-fpm` command when I start the docker container?

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM composer:1.6.5 as build
WORKDIR /var/www
COPY . /var/www
RUN composer install

FROM php:7.2-fpm
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    mysql-client \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y nginx
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data --from=build /var/www /var/www
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
EXPOSE 80

RUN service nginx restart
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I know I should run `php-fpm` because when I access 127.0.0.1:8080 it doesn't show my webpage. But when I ssh into the container and run `php-fpm` then visit 127.0.0.1:8080 again it will show the webpage.

Should I add `CMD ["php-fpm"]` below? Is it okay to have two `CMD` in the Dockerfile?

Comment: You should run `php-fpm` and `nginx` in separate containers.  A container only runs one main process; getting two in there can be tricky and isn't generally a recommended setup.

Comment: Yes I know, but in this case the `php-fpm` and `nginx` are in the same container. How do I run the `php-fpm` command when I start the container.

Answer (score 0):

It suggest that you create a start_service.sh script or whatever. to start both php_fpm and nginx when you start the container.

If the script its a good idea to both processes as daemons or in the background. And then just wait forever.

```
#!/bin/bash
"start php_fpm"
"start_iginx"
sleep infinite
```

In the CMD in the Dockerfile you just call your script instead of nginx.

Comment: why did you put `sleep infinite`?

Comment: The script will execute as the main process for the container, When you run the script it'll start php_fpm and continue, then start nginx and continue, both in the background. If you dont sleep then, the container will exit. You can also choose to start nginx in the fourground, but then it needs to be last and you cant do more in the script. A more general approach when you need to start more processes is to start them in the background and then wait in the script.